# How to change Permalink Structure in Custom Post Type Created Using ACF

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've created a custom post type in WordPress using the Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) plugin. However, I'm facing an issue with the URL structure. By default, the URL structure is in the format https://yourwebsite.com/custom-post-type/slug, but I want to remove the custom post type slug from the URL, so it appears as https://yourwebsite.com/slug.

Specifically, I want to know if there's a method within the ACF plugin to control the URL slug for custom post types or if there's a recommended way to modify the custom post type registration code to achieve this URL structure. Any advice or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your assistance!

I've tried changing the permalink settings in WordPress, but that didn't give me the desired result.